# r10K not configuring git correctly

Tags: puppet, r10k

i'm trying to setup puppet with r10k to dynamically deploy environments from a git repo hosted in Bitbucket.

The problem I'm having is that for each environment r10k configures git with the default branch set in Bitbucket rather with the actual branch.

Has anyone seen this behaviour before ?

Comment: It is somewhat unclear from your question, but are you referring to needing this functionality: https://puppet.com/docs/pe/2018.1/puppetfile.html#set-a-default-branch-for-content-deployment

Comment: Thank you @MattSchuchard however the git repos I'm talking about is not configured in my Puppetfile where external modules are declared but in /etc/puppetlabs/r10k/r10k.yaml as a source. r10k correctly makes an environment out of each branch but instead of tracking the upstream branch for each one it tracks whatever default branch has been configured in Bitbucket. This leaves the puppet environment / git repo in a detached head state given it is not checked out correctly.